# Служит ли запятая подчеркиванию реальной паузы в речи?

Tags: пунктуация

> — Вот вам, теперь, сооружайте башню!

Почему у Ф.М. Достоевского («Братья Карамазовы») после "теперь" — запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Трудно сказать, ставил ли эту запятую сам писатель: её могли поставить *корректоры* издательства (как в оригинальном издании, так и в одном из современных; случайно или намеренно). Вот вариант *без* запятой (правда, из сети):

http://book-cafe.ru/books.php?id=43&page=82

Для меня эта запятая не выглядит обязательной. Если попытаться её обосновать, то я бы задался вопросом, относится ли "теперь" к той же части предложения, что "сооружайте" (теперь сооружайте) или это слово по смыслу связано с междометием "вот вам" (как бы "вот вам, теперь ситуация изменилась").

Что касается обозначения паузы, то для произнесения такого текста (в понимании "теперь" как обстоятельства времени) она не нужна, если же *персонаж* "художественно" запнулся, то такая пауза (в рамках современной пунктуации) передаётся *многоточием*.

Comment: *Трудно сказать, ставил ли эту запятую сам писатель: её могли поставить корректоры издательства (как в оригинальном издании, так и в одном из современных; случайно или намеренно).* Вот именно!

Comment: А может ли быть так, что это предложение состоит из трех частей? Междометие, теперь и сооружайте башню. "Теперь" в таком случае выступило бы как обозначение чего-либо готовящегося к произнесению, в значении "вот сейчас, это важнейшее сейчас, в котором я кое-что непременно сообщу, но оно будет сейчас" - и сообщает: "Сооружайте башню!" - третью часть. "Теперь" как бы будет обладать относительной самостоятельностью.

Comment: Такое возможно, но трудно приписать этому "теперь" ясный смысл: слово воспринимается как элемент сбивчивой речи.

Answer (score 1):

***ВОт вам, теперь сооружАйте башню!***

У меня 12-томное собрание сочинений Достоевского (1982 года), нет там никакой запятой и быть не может.

Герой сообщает прокурору подробную информацию, а потом предлагает "сооружать башню".

Предложение состоит из двух фонетических фраз.  Наречие ***теперь*** нельзя обособить по смыслу, но разделить текст на три части в принципе можно, например:

*Вот вам, господин прокурор, сооружайте башню.*